# hazelcast - entry sizes are not equal on clusters

Tags: session, hazelcast

I am using :

```
hazelcast3.4
1 Load Balancer

2 cluster nodes 

1 distributed cache over that clusters(IMAP = sessionMap)
```

I have been running some performence scripts and  as I see on `hazelcastmancenter`, entry sizes for same map named `sessionMap` have not been equal:

### Memory

### 10.231.150.237 : 31987  entries 845

### 10.231.150.238 : 31987  entries 900

How can i solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned why the entry sizes are different on cluster nodes. Hazelcast does not equalize the entries on the clusters, It just combines the JVMs thus when you want to check the size of the distributed map , the total size equals sum of the entries on the clusters .
map.size = 845 +900 = 1745.